# Peeking behind ember-cli (EmberApp): vendor.js and app.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

With the excellent [broccoli-stew](https://github.com/stefanpenner/broccoli-stew) I can take a look at the exported application tree:

```
/* global require, module */

var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

var log   = require('broccoli-stew').log;
var debug = require('broccoli-stew').debug;

var app = new EmberApp();

// Use `app.import` to add additional libraries to the generated
// output files.
//
// If you need to use different assets in different
// environments, specify an object as the first parameter. That
// object's keys should be the environment name and the values
// should be the asset to use in that environment.
//
// If the library that you are including contains AMD or ES6
// modules that you would like to import into your application
// please specify an object with the list of modules as keys
// along with the exports of each module as its value.

app.import('bower_components/ember-i18n/lib/i18n.js');
app.import('bower_components/raphael/raphael.js');

var finalTree = log(app.toTree());

module.exports = finalTree;
```

With this I get a very clean tree-like output of my application:

```
[ 'assets/app.js',
  'assets/app.map',
  'assets/app.scss',
  ...
  'assets/vendor.css',
  'assets/vendor.js',
  'assets/vendor.map',
  'crossdomain.xml',
  'index.html',
  'robots.txt',
  'testem.js',
  'tests/index.html' ]
```

I see that in that tree we have, among other files, a `vendor.js` and an `app.js` modules (as expected), but I do not know what packages are put into each of them.

I have the feelling I am missing one in my frontend (in this case, `raphael.js`), so I would like to verify that `ember-cli` (via `EmberApp`)  has indeed done what I asked for (namely, include the `raphael.js`, probably in `vendor.js`)

Taking a direct look at `app.js` or `vendor.js` is not feasible (too big / don't know what to look for). I want a simple tree-like display of the files that have been included by `EmberApp` into `vendor.js` / `app.js`, in the same (similar) format that `broccoli-stew` is providing.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score -1):

To quote http://www.ember-cli.com/asset-compilation/#configuring-output-paths:

```
Assets                                          Output File
JavaScript files you import with app.import()   /assets/vendor.js
```

So although that is not a nice tree view, you should be fine :-)

Comment: That is what I *tell* EmberApp to do, not what EmberApp *does*. It is hopefully the same, but in my case that was *exactly* what I was not sure about. I wanted an independent way of listing the contents of `vendor.js`, and `app.js`.

Comment: If you really want to see what Ember is doing, have a look at the source of the function: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js#L1205. Open Source <3

Comment: By the same reasoning, I do not need `broccoli-stew`, or a debugger, or ... Just look at the code! And still, those tools are very useful. Anyway, I assume there is no way of listing the contents of `vendor.js` and `app.js` once they habe been generated.